# Return already present JSON strings with a Spring REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I have a REST API which provides JSON strings that are stored in a database.
The creation of the objects is time consuming, that is why I store the created JSON directly in the database.

| name | json |
| --- | --- |
| foo | "{...}" |
| bar | "{...}" |

Currently I return the strings and they have to be parsed on the client side.

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class RestApi {
    @GetMapping(value = "getbyname/{name}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> getByName(@PathVariable("name") final String name) {
        final String json = getJson(name);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(json);
    }

    public String getJson(final String name) {
        final String json;
        // get json from database
        return json;
    }
}
```

I want to expose the real classes to the client but use the already present JSON strings from the
database. Is there a way to add an already created JSON string on the server side, without
using String as return type? I want to do something like:

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class RestApi {
    @GetMapping(value = "getbyname/{name}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyClass> getByName(@PathVariable("name") final String name) {
        final String json = getJson(name);
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .type(MyClass.class) // Is something like this possible?
            .body(json);
    }

    public String getJson(final String name) {
        final String json;
        // get json from database
        return json;
    }
}
```

Of course I could parse the JSON string and return it, but I would be parsed into a JSON again and back to a object on the client side, which would just be unnecessary.